# Pandas concat ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to analyze the [Gizette Dataset](http://www.nipsfsc.ecs.soton.ac.uk/datasets/GISETTE.zip) from a Feature Selection Challenge

when i try to concat the train dataframe with the label series based on [pandas example](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-with-mixed-ndims) it

throws

> ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

trainData = pd.read_table(filepath_or_buffer='GISETTE/gisette_train.data'
                              ,delim_whitespace=True
                              ,header=None
                              ,names=['AA','AB','AC','AD','AE','AF','AG','AH','AI','AJ','AK','AL','AM','AN','AO','AP','AQ','AR','AS','AT','AU','AV','AW','AX','AY','AZ','BA','BB','BC','BD','BE','BF','BG','BH','BI','BJ','BK','BL','BM','BN','BO','BP','BQ','BR','BS','BT','BU','BV','BW','BX','BY','BZ','CA','CB','CC','CD','CE','CF','CG','CH','CI','CJ','CK','CL','CM','CN','CO','CP','CQ','CR','CS','CT','CU','CV','CW','CX','CY','CZ','DA','DB','DC','DD','DE','DF','DG','DH','DI','DJ','DK','DL','DM','DN','DO','DP','DQ','DR','DS','DT','DU','DV','DW','DX','DY','DZ','EA','EB','EC','ED','EE','EF','EG','EH','EI','EJ','EK','EL','EM','EN','EO','EP','EQ','ER','ES','ET','EU','EV','EW','EX','EY','EZ','FA','FB','FC','FD','FE','FF','FG','FH','FI','FJ','FK','FL','FM','FN','FO','FP','FQ','FR','FS','FT','FU','FV','FW','FX','FY','FZ','GA','GB','GC','GD','GE','GF','GG','GH','GI','GJ','GK','GL','GM','GN','GO','GP','GQ','GR','GS','GT','GU','GV','GW','GX','GY','GZ','HA','HB','HC','HD','HE','HF','HG','HH','HI','HJ','HK','HL','HM','HN','HO','HP','HQ','HR','HS','HT','HU','HV','HW','HX','HY','HZ','IA','IB','IC','ID','IE','IF','IG','IH','II','IJ','IK','IL','IM','IN','IO','IP','IQ','IR','IS','IT','IU','IV','IW','IX','IY','IZ','JA','JB','JC','JD','JE','JF','JG','JH','JI','JJ','JK','JL','JM','JN','JO','JP','JQ','JR','JS','JT','JU','JV','JW','JX','JY','JZ','KA','KB','KC','KD','KE','KF','KG','KH','KI','KJ','KK','KL','KM','KN','KO','KP','KQ','KR','KS','KT','KU','KV','KW','KX','KY','KZ','LA','LB','LC','LD','LE','LF','LG','LH','LI','LJ','LK','LL','LM','LN','LO','LP','LQ','LR','LS','LT','LU','LV','LW','LX','LY','LZ','MA','MB','MC','MD','ME','MF','MG','MH','MI','MJ','MK','ML','MM','MN','MO','MP','MQ','MR','MS','MT','MU','MV','MW','MX','MY','MZ','NA','NB','NC','ND','NE','NF','NG','NH','NI','NJ','NK','NL','NM','NN','NO','NP','NQ','NR','NS','NT','NU','NV','NW','NX','NY','NZ','OA','OB','OC','OD','OE','OF','OG','OH','OI','OJ','OK','OL','OM','ON','OO','OP','OQ','OR','OS','OT','OU','OV','OW','OX','OY','OZ','PA','PB','PC','PD','PE','PF','PG','PH','PI','PJ','PK','PL','PM','PN','PO','PP','PQ','PR','PS','PT','PU','PV','PW','PX','PY','PZ','QA','QB','QC','QD','QE','QF','QG','QH','QI','QJ','QK','QL','QM','QN','QO','QP','QQ','QR','QS','QT','QU','QV','QW','QX','QY','QZ','RA','RB','RC','RD','RE','RF','RG','RH','RI','RJ','RK','RL','RM','RN','RO','RP','RQ','RR','RS','RT','RU','RV','RW','RX','RY','RZ','SA','SB','SC','SD','SE','SF','SG','SH','SI','SJ','SK','SL','SM','SN','SO','SP','SQ','SR','SS','ST','SU','SV','SW','SX','SY','SZ','TA','TB','TC','TD','TE','TF'])
# print 'finished with train data'
trainLabel = pd.read_table(filepath_or_buffer='GISETTE/gisette_train.labels'
                           ,squeeze=True
                           ,names=['label']
                           ,delim_whitespace=True
                           ,header=None)
trainData.info()

# outputs
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 6000 entries   
Columns: 500 entries, AA to TF   
dtypes: int64(500)None



trainLabel.describe()

#outputs
count    6000.000000
mean        0.000000
std         1.000083
min        -1.000000
25%        -1.000000
50%         0.000000
75%         1.000000
max         1.000000
dtype: float64

readyToTrain = pd.concat([trainData, trainLabel], axis=1)
```

full stack trace

```
   File "C:\env\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 717, in concat  
     verify_integrity=verify_integrity)  
   File "C:\env\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 848, in __init__  
     self.new_axes = self._get_new_axes()  
   File "C:\env\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 898, in _get_new_axes  
     new_axes[i] = self._get_comb_axis(i)  
   File "C:\env\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 924, in _get_comb_axis  
     return _get_combined_index(all_indexes, intersect=self.intersect)  
   File "C:\env\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 3991, in _get_combined_index  
     union = _union_indexes(indexes)  
   File "C:\env\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 4017, in _union_indexes  
     result = result.union(other)  
   File "C:\env\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 3753, in union  
     uniq_tuples = lib.fast_unique_multiple([self.values, other.values])  
   File "lib.pyx", line 366, in pandas.lib.fast_unique_multiple (pandas\lib.c:8378)  
     ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'
```

edit:
installed library from binary from lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs pandas-0.14.1.win-amd64-py2.7

tried suggestion to convert series to frame (did not work same stacktrace as above) frame info:

dataframe info (trainData)

```
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    MultiIndex: 6000 entries, (550, 0, 495, 0, 0, 0, 0, 976, 0, 0, 0, 0, 983, 0, 995, 0, 983, 0, 0, 983, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 983, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 991, 983, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 808, 0, 778, 0, 983, 0, 0, 0, 0, 991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 991, 983, 983, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 983, 735, 0, 0, 983, 983, 0, 0, 0, 0, 569, 0, 0, 0, 0, 713, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 983, 983, 0, ...) to (0, 0, 991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 948, 995, 348, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 751, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 804, 0, 0, 0, 862, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 995, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 840, 0, 0, 0, 976, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 777, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...)
    Columns: 500 entries, AA to TF
    dtypes: int64(500)None
```

series to dataframe info (trainLabel):

```
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    Int64Index: 6000 entries, 0 to 5999
    Data columns (total 1 columns):
    label    6000 non-null int64
    dtypes: int64(1)None
```

Comment: How do you expect them to concatenate if the indexes are totally different (one a MultiIndex and the other a default integer index)?

Comment: I thought if you named the columns and didn't specify join then it would just create a data like [trainDataColumns, trainLabelColumn] i tried ignore_index=True but that didn't change anything

Comment: Nope, `concat` merges on the index. If you just want to merge them, you can reset the index of both (`reset_index`) and concatenate then.

Answer (score 3):

Like joris pointed out (and like I had to figure out myself because I did not read the comments first) the problems are your indexes.

Change your code from

```
pd.concat(to_concat, axis=1)
```

to

```
pd.concat([s.reset_index(drop=True) for s in to_concat], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because of mismatch in index of both dataframe when you try to concat it. I figured out the way to concat this two dataframe. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

trainData = pd.read_table(filepath_or_buffer='/Users/embibe/Desktop/kaggle/gisette/gisette_train.data'
                              ,delim_whitespace=True
                              ,header=None
                              ,names=['AA','AB','AC','AD','AE','AF','AG','AH','AI','AJ','AK','AL','AM','AN','AO','AP','AQ','AR','AS','AT','AU','AV','AW','AX','AY','AZ','BA','BB','BC','BD','BE','BF','BG','BH','BI','BJ','BK','BL','BM','BN','BO','BP','BQ','BR','BS','BT','BU','BV','BW','BX','BY','BZ','CA','CB','CC','CD','CE','CF','CG','CH','CI','CJ','CK','CL','CM','CN','CO','CP','CQ','CR','CS','CT','CU','CV','CW','CX','CY','CZ','DA','DB','DC','DD','DE','DF','DG','DH','DI','DJ','DK','DL','DM','DN','DO','DP','DQ','DR','DS','DT','DU','DV','DW','DX','DY','DZ','EA','EB','EC','ED','EE','EF','EG','EH','EI','EJ','EK','EL','EM','EN','EO','EP','EQ','ER','ES','ET','EU','EV','EW','EX','EY','EZ','FA','FB','FC','FD','FE','FF','FG','FH','FI','FJ','FK','FL','FM','FN','FO','FP','FQ','FR','FS','FT','FU','FV','FW','FX','FY','FZ','GA','GB','GC','GD','GE','GF','GG','GH','GI','GJ','GK','GL','GM','GN','GO','GP','GQ','GR','GS','GT','GU','GV','GW','GX','GY','GZ','HA','HB','HC','HD','HE','HF','HG','HH','HI','HJ','HK','HL','HM','HN','HO','HP','HQ','HR','HS','HT','HU','HV','HW','HX','HY','HZ','IA','IB','IC','ID','IE','IF','IG','IH','II','IJ','IK','IL','IM','IN','IO','IP','IQ','IR','IS','IT','IU','IV','IW','IX','IY','IZ','JA','JB','JC','JD','JE','JF','JG','JH','JI','JJ','JK','JL','JM','JN','JO','JP','JQ','JR','JS','JT','JU','JV','JW','JX','JY','JZ','KA','KB','KC','KD','KE','KF','KG','KH','KI','KJ','KK','KL','KM','KN','KO','KP','KQ','KR','KS','KT','KU','KV','KW','KX','KY','KZ','LA','LB','LC','LD','LE','LF','LG','LH','LI','LJ','LK','LL','LM','LN','LO','LP','LQ','LR','LS','LT','LU','LV','LW','LX','LY','LZ','MA','MB','MC','MD','ME','MF','MG','MH','MI','MJ','MK','ML','MM','MN','MO','MP','MQ','MR','MS','MT','MU','MV','MW','MX','MY','MZ','NA','NB','NC','ND','NE','NF','NG','NH','NI','NJ','NK','NL','NM','NN','NO','NP','NQ','NR','NS','NT','NU','NV','NW','NX','NY','NZ','OA','OB','OC','OD','OE','OF','OG','OH','OI','OJ','OK','OL','OM','ON','OO','OP','OQ','OR','OS','OT','OU','OV','OW','OX','OY','OZ','PA','PB','PC','PD','PE','PF','PG','PH','PI','PJ','PK','PL','PM','PN','PO','PP','PQ','PR','PS','PT','PU','PV','PW','PX','PY','PZ','QA','QB','QC','QD','QE','QF','QG','QH','QI','QJ','QK','QL','QM','QN','QO','QP','QQ','QR','QS','QT','QU','QV','QW','QX','QY','QZ','RA','RB','RC','RD','RE','RF','RG','RH','RI','RJ','RK','RL','RM','RN','RO','RP','RQ','RR','RS','RT','RU','RV','RW','RX','RY','RZ','SA','SB','SC','SD','SE','SF','SG','SH','SI','SJ','SK','SL','SM','SN','SO','SP','SQ','SR','SS','ST','SU','SV','SW','SX','SY','SZ','TA','TB','TC','TD','TE','TF'])
trainLabel = pd.read_table(filepath_or_buffer='/Users/embibe/Desktop/kaggle/gisette/gisette_train.labels'
                           ,squeeze=True
                           ,names=['label']
                           ,delim_whitespace=True
                           ,header=None)
trainData.describe()
trainData = trainData.reset_index()
trainData = trainData.iloc[:,-500:]
trainData.describe()
trainData.shape
trainLabel.shape
df = pd.concat([trainData, trainLabel], axis=1)
df.head()
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

I've read it is easier to just create the whole table as a nested list, and then create the pandas DataFrame using that nested list.