# python pandas code that used to work fine but not anymore

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, valueerror

```
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'
```

this stuff came out to the exactly same code that worked fine before

there is a column called buyer. the code below is for collecting the rows with 'st' value in buyer column. existing df is the df that existed and I made a variable for st_only_existing_df.

```
existing_df = pandas.read_sql("select * from collection",conn)
st_only_existing_df = existing_df[existing_df.buyer.isin(['st'])]
```

so from newly downloaded data(st_essential_df.ordernum) to st_only_existing_df, I compared ordernum and if there isn't the data anymore at newly downloaded data, then I put canceled message to the orderstatus.

```
    canceled_df = st_only_existing_df[~st_only_existing_df.ordernum.isin(st_essential_df.ordernum)]
     for index, row in canceled_df.iterrows():

         odrnum = row['ordernum']
         c.execute("update collection set orderstatus='canceled' where ordernum=?", (odrnum,))
         conn.commit()
```

The code above worked just fine. but it isn't anymore. I don't know why it returned 'long long'.

actually, I have to download the order data from many various buyers. one of them is 'we'. when working on 'we' data importing code, I found the same error. but it dissapeared. 
and after I made success from 'we'data inputting to sqlite3, db file got 'we'data, and suddenly, st db inputting isn't working.
I don't think that will make any difference but....

is there anyone who have some clue for me?

Comment: have a look here. It seems that they solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822604/pandas-concat-valueerror-buffer-dtype-mismatch-expected-python-object-but-go